# Strange behavior with SceneKit Node

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

I created a circular array objects, no problems.

When I rotate there appears to be a sinc or gaussian function at the center.

The camera is a z 60, radius of structure is 30.

Initial view, no artifacts
[image]

Rotated 90 deg up, no artifacts
[image]

Rotated 180 deg, artifact appears in center of object
[image]

Continued rotation, artifact is still there.
[image]

The code for the object is here

```
  class func Build(scene: SCNScene) -> SCNNode {

    let radius: Double = 30.0
    let numberOfStrands: Int = 24

    //Create the base chromosomes.
    let baseChromosome = SCNBox(width: 4.0, height: 24, length: 1.0, chamferRadius: 0.5)
    let baseChromosomes = DNA.buildCircleOfObjects(baseChromosome, numberOfItems: numberOfStrands, radius: radius)
    baseChromosomes.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0.5, z: 0)
    return baseChromosomes

  }

  class func buildCircleOfObjects(_geometry: SCNGeometry, numberOfItems: Int, radius: Double) -> SCNNode {

    var x: Double = 0.0
    var z: Double = radius
    let theta: Double = (M_PI) / Double(numberOfItems / 2)
    let incrementalY: Double = (M_PI) / Double(numberOfItems) * 2

    let nodeCollection = SCNNode()
    nodeCollection.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0.5, z: 0)

    for index in 1...numberOfItems {

      x = radius * sin(Double(index) * theta)
      z = radius * cos(Double(index) * theta)

      let node = SCNNode(geometry: _geometry)
      node.position = SCNVector3(x: Float(x), y: 0, z:Float(z))

      let rotation = Float(incrementalY) * Float(index)
      node.rotation = SCNVector4(x: 0, y: 1, z: 0, w: rotation)
      nodeCollection.addChildNode(node)

    }

    return nodeCollection

  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not scenekit pro, but for a radius of 30, if the camera z defines how much space the object has to move around in, I don't think 60 is going to be enough for a cylinder with a non-zero height.  What happens if you use a larger camera z (or smaller radius)?

Comment: I think you're right, it's a combination of xFov, yFov, zNear, zFar... initially I thought maybe a strange culling effect.

Comment: these settings finally worked    `cameraNode.camera?.xFov = 60
    cameraNode.camera?.yFov  = 60
    cameraNode.camera?.zFar = 1000
    cameraNode.camera?.zNear = 0.01`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using these settings

```
cameraNode.camera?.xFov = 60
cameraNode.camera?.yFov  = 60
cameraNode.camera?.zFar = 1000
cameraNode.camera?.zNear = 0.01
```

the artifacts disappeared.  I think this is a problem with zFar, it should have clipped the back surface uniformly not like a lens aberration.

Comment: It *is* clipping uniformly.  Realize that your ring is at an angle.  Think of the back-wall as being a wall of light.  As you tilt a cylinder into this wall of light, think about the way in which the light will start shining on which parts...

Comment: See also [`automaticallyAdjustsZRange`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNCamera_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SCNCamera/automaticallyAdjustsZRange).

Answer (score 0):

Falling out of [Viewing frustum](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viewing_frustum) may be the one to cause most problem. However there is another common cause by misunderstanding the behavior of SCNView's [allowsCameraControl](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnview/1523171-allowscameracontrol), that is when you Pinch to zoom in or zoom out (change the camera's fieldOfView), but the pointOfView's position reminds the same.

Your nodes still stand BEHIND the pointOfView, however small the camera's zNear is. Hence you see them got clipped. The code below may help you in this case, at least avoid the problem.

```
sceneView.pointOfView!.simdPosition 
= float3(0, 0, -scene.rootNode.boundingSphere.radius)
```